# Precompiled headers, опция Force Include и забытые инклуды

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pch

Я использую в своих проектах precompiled headers и опцию Visual Studio "force include", чтобы не засорять свои и чужие исходники записями `#include "stdafx.h"`

В stdafx.h перечислены наиболее часто используемые заголовочные файлы:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlapp.h>
#include <atlwin.h>
//...
```

Проблема в том, что при использовании такого подхода, модули становятся не самодостаточными. Кое-где я забываю сделать, например, `#include <map>`, и при компиляции без использования PCH (у меня много подпроектов в проекте, использующих разные системы сборки, но одни и те же файлы), я получаю ошибку.

Как не допустить появления таких ошибок? Кроме как переодически перекомпилировать с выключенной опцией Force Include.

Comment: А почему бы не убрать force include для компиляции на build-сервере? Но конечно придётся объяснить команде, почему ошибка не воспроизводится на локальной машине.

Comment: Ответ очевиден - никак.

Comment: А почему `stdafx.h` засоряет проект? Переименуйте его в `commonheaders.h` (и в свойствах проекта тоже), и уберите force include. А?

Comment: У меня нет никакой команды и билд-сервера. 
И никаких commonheaders тоже нет, в разных подпроектах это могут быть разные заголовочные файлы, плюс еще у меня кроссплатформенное приложение, на разных системах разные инклуды.

Comment: Если приложение кроссплатформенное. то использовать force include тем более странно. Всё это делается в одном файле PCH с макросами, и PCH подключаются в каждой системе по своему.

Comment: Я частично следую Google C++ Style guide. Вот что он советует:
`The usual way of working with precompiled headers is to include a header file at the top of each source file, typically with a name like StdAfx.h or precompile.h. To make your code easier to share with other projects, avoid including this file explicitly (except in precompile.cc), and use the /FI compiler option to include the file automatically.`
Отказываться от PCH я не собираюсь, он сокращает время компиляции на порядок.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, в Chromium тоже используются Force Includes на винде, а это огромный кроссплатформенный проект.

Comment: Вам интересно следовать советам гугла, или задачу решать? Очевидно ведь, что в Вашем случае такое не проходит. Force include не даёт Вам достичь цели. Значит надо либо оставить цель, либо отказаться от force include.